# Changing the script reference in HTML file when a button is pressed

Tags: javascript, html, frontend

I am trying to change the entire layout of my site when the submit button is pressed. So I find it easier to switch between two JS scripts rather than trying to cram everything into one, but the page isn't responding to change in script, even though the console shows the change in the script reference. I have added the relevant snapshots below. Thank you for reading my problem...

```html
<script src="prac.js"></script>
```

```js
button.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0].src = 'main.js';
    console.log(document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]);
});
```

EDIT : I am new to this forum so I did not know about the code insertion. I'm sorry about that. Also the console message essentially showed an expexted change in script reference but the website layout did not change.

EDIT 2 : The suggested deletion and appending of new script does indeed work, but can someone explain why altering the current script tag ends in failure?

Comment: Please add code snippets instead of screenshots of code.

Comment: post the relevant code as text and not as images.

Comment: Please don't post images of code. Search engines and visually impaired people can't read the text in images, and no one wants to retype your code into their IDE just to help you. Please respect the time of the volunteers who help you.

Comment: Please consider to use code snippets instead of code screenshot. The editorf of stackoverflow provide good features for this.

Comment: What is the content of main.js? Just copy and paste it into the question, then select the lines again and press Ctrl+k.

Comment: Hello, I'd recommend you to use JQuery, to make the work easier.

Comment: Add complete example using code snippet please

Answer (score 1):

**Remove the script element from DOM and add another script like this:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="demo1.js"></script>
</head> 
<script>
    window.onload = function(){
        var firstScript = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; //get first script
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].removeChild(firstScript); //removing it from DOM <head> tag
        var secondScript = document.createElement('script'); //creating another script
        secondScript.src = "demo2.js";  //adding source to it
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(secondScript); //adding script to DOM          
    };
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: This is the part where you script code should work according to your implementation(layout change), you can check the script loading changes inside Developer tools > Network. you can also post your script code if your layout is not changing. Upvote me for the same.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked, however could you explain why changing the current tag does not work? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just because DOM is detecting changes when an element is added into it, not for script reference being change, if you want to see your current tag changes work, I would recommend you to delete the script and then add into DOM for your changes to work. DOM looks for a new script tag being added into it, then it renders it and loads your resource.